# A question about positive forms on involutive algebras.

Tags: representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

A linear form $f$ on an involutive algebra $A$ is said to be positive if $f(x^\ast x)\geq 0$ for every $x$ in $A$.

To be useful, this definition requires that is not always possible to write $-(x^\ast x)=y^\ast y$ for some y.

How can I prove this fact?

Answer (score 1):

In such generality, what you want is not true. You can take $A=\mathbb C$, and take the trivial involution $z^*=z$. Then
$$
-(2i)^*2i=2^*2.
$$